# Load Excel data into SQL Server using SSIS without Creating tables in the target

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS and am not sure if this is possible to upload Excel data into SQL Server without creating table schema, where the Job automatically creates the table schema according to the source file? I used to do this using SAP Data Integrator with Template table component and I am not sure if there is a similar functionality in SSIS

Answer (score 1):

There is no capability in SSIS to interpret the structure from the source file and create the table schema.  You can create tables as part of the SSIS control flow, but the data flows that load the data are very fussy about knowing the source and target structure at design time.  In other words, it doesn't handle dynamic structures very well.

Comment: I guess a script task is the only way. But SSIS does have the ability through writing code.